# How do I create a storage account context using system assigned managed identity, in Azure Function running Powershell - Consumption Plan?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, serverless

I have developed an Azure Function responsible for exporting files to a storage account. During the testing phase, I utilized a Shared Access Signature (SAS) connection string, employing the PowerShell script below to establish a storage account context:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString $storageConnectionString
```

As we move to the production environment, I aim to leverage the system-assigned managed identity of the Azure Function, which holds a storage account contributor role in the designated storage account.

To achieve this, I have attempted to create a storage account context using the managed identity. However, the New-AzStorageContext cmdlet lacks a direct parameter for managed identity, leading to the following unsuccessful attempt:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount -AssignedIdentityId $managedIdentityClientId
```

I am currently exploring alternative approaches to use the managed identity, such as obtaining the object ID. Any suggestions or guidance on how to successfully create a storage account context with the managed identity would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use **`Managed Identity`** of **`Function App`** to connect to **`Azure storage account`**, Utilize the Method below:-

***Azure Functions Identity:-***

[image]

***Azure Storage Account assigned Role:-***

[image]

Function App **`Http Trigger code`** to connect to storage account:-

```
using namespace System.Net


param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)


Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."


$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}


Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Storage


Connect-AzAccount -Identity


$AccountName = "siliconrgps843f"
$ResourceGroupName = "siliconrgps"


$StorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $AccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName


$storageAccountJson = $StorageAccount | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $storageAccountJson
})
```

I am using below code to *Connect to my Azure account with Function App managed Identity* Reference [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-11.2.0#example-5-connect-using-a-managed-service-identity):-

```
# Authenticate with Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
```

Also, You cannot add storage account context for Managed Identity as that is not available option according to this [***MS Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-11.2.0).

[image]